# TOOL-BARS: How do toolbars manage to insert new settings on to the users computer when legitimate programs can't/won't do it?

Tags: chrome, internet

I accidentally installed Ask Toolbar, and it changed my Homepage,Search engine and added some extra stuff. It did all this without alerting Google Chrome!

But when I try to install a legitimate search engine like DuckDuckGo, I have to do a lot of manual work compared to the Ask Toolbar which seems to automate installing the settings.

I was wondering why does't DuckDuckGo use the same methods as Ask?

Is it due to security issues of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed Ask there was a check box which was enabled by default that gave a high level of permissions to the toolbar. So it doesn't need to ask for these permissions in future.

I have not used duckduckgo, but I assume it is a bit more polite, and asks for specific permissions.